# Oracle SQL - Joining with an "OR" condition

Tags: sql, oracle, join, left-join

This is my second post today, so I am sorry for flooding the forums.

I am having trouble conceptually grasping how to accomplish what I need to do.

I have one table with contains my PART_NUM, and a separate field called "LOWER_PART_NUM" which is a smaller component of the bigger part (imagine a chainsaw. The teeth are the LOWER_PART_NUM and the whole unit is the PART_NUM).

I then have a table that has numbers, and names. It is two columns.

I am looking to JOIN my table that has all of my part numbers with my name table, where the name table would fill in the blank values for both PART_NUM OR LOWER_PART_NUM depending on which matched. Here is an example:

[image]

It would have to be a left join, because every part doesn't always have a lower part (we also don't go below one level, so no worries there).

I can't figure out, however, how to set up the SQL query... because if I do

```
SELECT PART_NUM, LOWER_PART_NUM, PART_PRICE
FROM PARTS
LEFT JOIN PART_NAMES ON PARTS.PART_NUM = PART_NAMES.PART_NUM
```

Then I miss getting the names for the lower... but

```
SELECT PART_NUM, LOWER_PART_NUM, PART_NAME, PART_PRICE
FROM PARTS
LEFT JOIN PART_NAMES ON PARTS.LOWER_PART_NUM = PART_NAMES.PART_NUM
```

Could anybody help me logically figure this out? I would appreciate any advice.

Thank you!

Comment: When I look on your 'joined table' (expected output?) the use your query without `LEFT`

Comment: @RadimBača the jointed table is what I am hoping to achieve... a table where I will have (if  applicable) the part numbers AND their names. I had no issue before when I was dealing with just PART_NUM, but my group is now concerned with adding in LOWER_PART_NUM and getting it's name, too.

Comment: please post your tables as text and not as pictures.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am pretty sure that you are looking at a [UNION](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/union.php) here and probably [DISTINCT](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/distinct.php).  The query would look something like this:

```
Select distinct U.* 
from (
    SELECT PART_NUM, LOWER_PART_NUM, PART_PRICE
    FROM PARTS
    LEFT JOIN PART_NAMES ON PARTS.PART_NUM = PART_NAMES.PART_NUM
UNION ALL
    SELECT PART_NUM, LOWER_PART_NUM, PART_NAME, PART_PRICE
    FROM PARTS
    LEFT JOIN PART_NAMES ON PARTS.LOWER_PART_NUM = PART_NAMES.PART_NUM
) U;
```

Comment: I think this is where I should be headed. I am working on implementation now and will let you know. Thank you

Comment: Though I am over a year late, this ended up being the solution.

Answer (score 2):

You should use two time the PART_NAMES table for join boths the values PART_NUM and LOWER_PART_NUM

```
SELECT A.PART_NUM, B.PART_NAME, A.LOWER_PART_NUM, C.PART_NAME, A.PART_PRICE, A.OPERATOR_TYPE
FROM PARTS A
LEFT JOIN PART_NAMES B ON A.PART_NUM = B.PART_NUM
LEFT JOIN PART_NAMES C ON A.LOWER_PART_NUM = C.PART_NUM
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately I tried that and it threw an "ambiguous join" error.

Comment: answer  udate  .. the second is lower_part_num

Comment: @bm0r3son i think you forgot to vote up for this nice answer, friend :)

Answer (score 0):

scaisEdge had the right idea.

As long as you assign an alias to each table when you join it, you won't get the ambiguous join error.

In my query below, I created the data in your screenshot using with clauses and then left joined each one. I gave them each different names (MainPart and LowerPart).

```
with part_table as
(select '500ABX' PART_NUM, '226K333L1V' LOWER_PART_NUM, 312 PART_PRICE, 'A' OPERATOR_TYPE from dual union all
 select '321AELL','1230419ABKEL',25000,'A' from dual)
, part_name as
(select '500ABX' PART_NUM, 'Hand Crane' PART_NAME from dual union all
 select '321AELL', 'Forklift' from dual union all
 select '226K333L1V', 'Wheels' from dual union all
 select '1230419ABKEL', 'FL Wheels' from dual)

select part_table.part_num,
       MainPart.part_name,
       LowerPart.part_num,
       LowerPart.part_name,
       part_table.part_price,
       part_table.operator_type
from part_table
left join part_name MainPart
 on part_table.part_num = MainPart.part_num
left join part_name LowerPart
 on part_table.lower_part_num = LowerPart.part_num
```

Output:

```
PART_NUM    PART_NAME   LOWER_PART_NUM      LOWER_PART_NAME     PART_PRICE      OPERATOR_TYPE
500ABX      Hand Crane  226K333L1V          Wheels              312             A
321AELL     Forklift    1230419ABKEL        FL Wheels           25000           A
```